# What kind of applications use getopt "return in order" behavior?

Tags: java, c, linux, unix, command-line

Quoted from the [getopt() Linux Manual page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getopt.3.html):

> If the first character of ***optstring*** is a <kbd>hyphen</kbd> (<kbd>-</kbd>), then each nonoption argv-element is handled as if it were the argument of an option with character code 1.  (This is used by programs that were written to expect options and other argv-elements in any order and that care about the ordering of the two.)  The special argument <kbd>double hyphens</kbd> (<kbd>--</kbd>) forces an end of option-scanning regardless of the scanning mode.

Quoted from the [manual page of Java GetOpt class](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/api/gnu/getopt/Getopt.html):

> ...The second is to allow options anywhere, but to return all elements in the order they occur on the command line. When a non-option element is ecountered, an integer 1 is returned and the value of the non-option element is stored in optarg is if it were the argument to that option. For example, "-a foo -d", returns first 'a', then 1 (with optarg set to "foo") then 'd' then -1. When this "return in order" functionality is enabled, the only way to stop getopt() from scanning all command line elements is to use the special "--" string by itself as described above. An example is "-a foo -b -- bar", which would return 'a', then integer 1 with optarg set to "foo", then 'b', then -1. optind would then point to "bar" as the first non-option argv element. The "--" is discarded.

Yes, I understand what the above statements talking about, but I still cannot imagine what kind of applications use such a behaviour.

Could someone provides an example of a command-line syntax that likely used by applications that implement the "return in order" behavior?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, it's the digit 1.

Comment: The font of the linked manual page is really treacherous, [here is a link](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) to another with better font, where you can _really_ see the difference between `1` and `l`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I have edited the phrase you mentioned back to the orginal phrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` is an example of a command that mixes options and non-option arguments, and cares about the order.